# Можно ли как то вывести график с keepa.com?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Можно ли как то вывести график с `keepa.com` на свою страницу сайта?
Я знаю что его выводит `iframe` благодаря расширению в браузере, но если я передаю ссылку на товар в своем `iframe`, то просто выводиться страница сайта без графика, но расширение как-то его выводит. Задача: Вывести список товаров и рядом с ними график этого товара с `keepa.com` можно картинкой, но я не знаю как. С `iframe` тоже не получается.

Comment: Картинка из Share Graph вам не подходит?

Comment: 1) Любопытное приложение, спасибо. 2) Что Вы делали и как? Код, видео, голозапись. 3) Реверсить надо.

Comment: "Картинка из Share Graph вам не подходит?" А что это?

Comment: Когда смотрим график на конкретном товаре внизу есть ссылки/кнопки. Одна из них `Share Graph`, по нажатию на которую можно получит ссылку на картинку с данным графиком. Картинка поддерживается в актуальном состоянии графика.

Comment: Спс большое я не знал.